# Best way to programming page for this iOS app - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, paging, scroll-paging

[3 fullscreen pages with different uielements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8djfx.png)
I need 3 fullscreen pages (in that moment) with different UIElements. Tell me pls best way to do that? Different VC? CollectionView? ScrollView?

Answer (score 1):

for pager you can use the pageviewcontroller or collectionviewcontroller in paging mode
https://medium.com/@shaibalassiano/tutorial-horizontal-uicollectionview-with-paging-9421b479ee94